# Nginx config for multiple Laravel applications always returns just one

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to use single server to host multiple Laravel applications with Nginx and PHP-FPM.
The problem is that only one application is being loaded no matter the domain.

I have an A DNS record for each app:

- **a.example.com**
- **b.example.com**

When i visit **a.example.com** i get into the **A** application. But when i visit **b.example.com**, **A** application responds again!!

On the server, there are 2 Nginx configs, taken from the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment)

```
#/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/a.example.com

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name a.example.com;
    root /var/www/a/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and

```
#/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/b.example.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name b.example.com;
    root /var/www/b/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**The most interesting part** is that when I rename **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/a.example.com** to **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/c.example.com** and restart Nginx, then the situation is opposite, I always end up in the **B application**

So my question is - what am i missing?

Comment: whats in your `nginx.conf`? also, is that just a typo where your config file extension is `.com` instead of that `.conf` or is that how you pull the files inside your `nginx.conf`

Comment: `nginx.conf` is default i.e. it wasnt changed from a fresh install.

As for file extension it's not a typo. Configs inside of sites-enabled does not have to have any extension or can have any extension. Most tutorials i stumbled upon name their config as per server_name but it could be a.example.com or a.conf or just a.

Answer (score 0):

this `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` is not a default nginx set-up, this kind of set-up mostly taken from apache configuration, I've seen many nginx tutorials that follows this config, and it can be more confusing if you are not familiar with nginx.

the default configuration of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` only includes config files located inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

you'll see that at the end line of nginx default `http` block

```
http {
    .
    .
    .
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

the fact that your configuration file is not properly working, it appears like its only pulling one config file which sets as the default server.

I'd always advise you'd stick with the default nginx config set-up and make sure your `http` block has this line `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

then put your config file inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory that should have a `.conf` extension

i.e.

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/0000-default.conf`  - contains server block for your default server, any domain pointed on your server without config file will use this.

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/b.example.com.conf` - server block for `b.example.com`
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/c.example.com.conf` - server block for `c.example.com`

Comment: Actually, in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf i see that it loads both *.conf and sites-enabled:
# Virtual Host Configs
##
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

Comment: try moving your config inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` your set-up only loads the first file inside sites-enabled for some reason, you see it only loads `a` config and when you change the file name from `a` to `c`, the `b` will become the first file and load as default